# Can you have standardised warnings across Eclipse and IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

We use a both Eclipse and IntelliJ in my team. Is there a way to set IntelliJ to have exactly the same inspection/warning profile as the one Eclipse uses?

It would be useful for all of us to see exactly the same warnings on the same piece of code even if we're in different IDEs.

Comment: I would think that FindBug/CheckStyle profiles would be independent of IDEs

Answer (score 2):

Use [SonarQube](http://sonarqube.com/) and the respective browser plugins. I know from experience that the [Eclipse plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse) is excellent, and from screenshots, [the IntelliJ one](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238) looks quite good too.

This way you don't worry about individual devs reconfiguring their preferences.